# Storing the SVN working copy on a server using sshfs

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, sshfs

I am using Tortoise SVN to interact with our repository.
When i'm developing i would like to test the code i'm working on instantly.
Thats why i want to store my working copy on the webserver using sshfs.

When checking out in this mounted drive, Tortoise gives me the following error:
Error: database is locked, executing statement 'PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;PRAGMA  
Error: recursive_triggers=ON;'

checking out to local folders or copying local folders to the mounted drive works.

Is this a problem with any configurations on the server or a limitation of sshfs ?

Answer (score 1):

Subversion uses [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) to store the metadata of a working copy. And SQLite has some [specific requirements](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#how_to_corrupt) on the filesystem it is stored on.

I'm pretty sure that sshfs does not support the correct locking that SQLite requires.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that makes sense.
Is there a workaround for this ? Or is there any other workflow that has the same result 
The purpose is to test my code while working on the working copy. Without setting up a local webserver.

Comment: @Jeroen - checkout (on server) repo to WC inside web-space, update this (server-side) WC in post-commit hook

Comment: So that means that i have to use svn (checkout) from the command line right ?
I can't do that with tortoise right?